# Manually create an audit table for Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I understand Envers generates a table to store the audit trail. Is it possible to manually assign a table where I want the data to be stored. Instead of allowing Envers to generate a table by itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only generate the tables if you are using one of the ddl auto options.

If you want to control the naming of the audit tables during this process or, create the tables yourself  and have them named differently then you specify the value for the @AuditTable annotation and/or specify the prefix and suffix in the configuration.

Additionally, you can control/specify the name of the global REVINFO table using the @RevisionEntity annotation.

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#tables

All of which is detailed in the comprehensive documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#tables

Comment: So, let me get this right. Say I've a model class called Person which I annotate with @Audited. When I save/update the entity. The changes can be saved into a manually create table of my choice like Person_History instead of Envers generating something called Person_AUD?

Comment: I just don't see any property where I can assign to Envers to use this existing table called Person_History to persist the history.

Comment: As the documentation clearly states use the @AuditTable("Person_History") annotation on your Entity.